# variadic template with mixed reference and non-reference type

Tags: templates, boost-asio, variadic-templates

I need a Register some functions with variadic templates like

```
std::function<R(Args...)>;
```

so i can register class member functions like this:

```
std::function<void(std::string)> F1 = [this](std::string msg)->void {Fun1(msg); };
RegisterCmd(1, F1);
```

or

```
std::function<void(int ,double )> F = [this](int p1 ,double p2)->void {Fun2(p1,p2); };
RegisterCmd(2,F2);
```

and the variadic template function is like:

```
template<typename R,typename... Args> bool RegisterCmd(uint16_t CmdId, std::function <R(Args...)> RealFunc);
```

but now  i have to pass some non-copyable variable by reference like

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_
```

so i have to change the variadic template function to

```
template<typename R,typename... Args> bool RegisterCmd(uint16_t CmdId, std::function <R(Connection & ,Args...)> RealFunc);
```

but this causes a lot of changes in the template hpp file.
Is there any way of to solve the problem elegantly?